# kubectl apply says pod created however get pods shows nothing

Tags: kubernetes

I just ran `kubectl apply -f` and got a response that `pod/mypod` got created
with no error messages or anything

Then I did a `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and there is no trace of mypod!

How can I troubleshoot the pod creation? Where would these logs be, if any?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
kubectl get event -n name_space
```

is a good start to see what went wrong which showed me Volume mount issue

An even better command to call is:

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look at the logs from each of the Kubernetes components. You can start with the [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) to see what happened after the request was received. Then the [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/), and so forth.

This is likely due to Kubernetes not being able to find resources to run your pod. Are your nodes healthy? You can check them:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

You can also look at the logs of your [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) on your nodes.

Notice that when you get the message `pod/mypod got created` it means that the objects were created in the cluster's state store ([etcd](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd))

Comment: thanks. Get nodes is healthy. I have a namespace to which I am deploying this pod and that is also healthy
I did a get event and i'm seeing mount volume errors

Comment: Could you add a line or two on how to see the logs for  kube-apiserver and kube-scheduler ? that would make this answer more complete

Comment: It really depends where your kubernetes control plane is running. EKS? Do you have access to the masters?

Comment: I'm running this locally on my ubuntu. I used kubeadm to create the cluster